# Determine driver for network interface

Tags: linux, devices, network-interface

I wanted to see which driver was associated with some of the network interfaces listed by `ip link`. My first thought was to find the network interfaces in `/dev` and look at the device major and minor numbers to determine the associated driver. However, network interfaces don't appear under `/dev`.

I'm have a feeling I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about the Linux network stack (perhaps because multiple kernel modules can be involved because of netfilter/iptables/tc), so please address this if so. My naive questions are:

- How do you determine which driver performs I/O for a particular network interface?
- Why don't Linux network interfaces appear in `/dev`?

Comment: `lspci` command should list the driver, I guess.

Comment: inxi will do it if it works on your distribution.

Comment: I closed this since your basic question is a direct duplicate. Your second question is a different matter but please don't ask separate questions on the same post. Feel free to ask the second one by itself.

Comment: `lshw -c network`

Comment: @Ramesh lspci is too generic.

Comment: Yup. I didn't find the other one because I searched for "network interface" instead of "device.".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm never quite sure if spelunking in sysfs is the best way to do things (am I supposed to use udevadm?), but at least it's discoverable

```
$ DEV=p8p1
$ readlink /sys/class/net/$DEV/device/driver
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/tg3
```

---

It won't work for devices like `lo` which are "virtual" (`/sys/devices/virtual/`).  They don't have the link to an underlying `device` (e.g. on the pci bus), so you can't query the driver as above.

---

There's also a linux-specific tool `ethtool`.  It uses an eponymous socket ioctl instead of reading sysfs.  The ioctl is linux-specific; standard unix APIs don't tell you what the driver is called.  `ethtool` gives the same result (it doesn't work for `lo` and the extra information is pointless).

```
$ ethtool -i p8p1
driver: tg3
version: 3.137
firmware-version: sb
bus-info: 0000:04:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```